# Hiding row/column in Quicksight

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I have a table like this:

|  | Jan | Feb | March |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sales | Cell 2 | Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| Order | Cell 2 | Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| Revenue | Cell 2 | Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| Cancellation | Cell 2 | Cell 1 | Cell 2 |

How can i create a drop down filter such that if i select sales and orders only those rows are visible. I use quicksight.

Seems like there is no such options directly available. Hence i am looking for a work around